# theano: row-wise outer product between two matrices

Tags: numpy, theano

I'm trying to compute the row-wise outer-product between two matrices in theano, without using scan. I can do this in numpy by using einsum, which isn't available in theano.

```
A = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])
B = np.array([[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]])
print np.einsum('xi,xj->xij', A, B)
[[[3 3 3 3]
  [3 3 3 3]
  [3 3 3 3]]

 [[8 8 8 8]
  [8 8 8 8]
  [8 8 8 8]]]
```

Comment: I thought this was a simple question; but I must say the answer eludes me so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be doable using some reshaping: Many of the simple einsum operations boil down to that. The complicated ones don't.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]).astype('float32')
b = np.array([[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]).astype('float32')

A = T.fmatrix()
B = T.fmatrix()

C = A[:, :, np.newaxis] * B[:, np.newaxis, :]

print C.eval({A:a, B:b})
```

results in

```
[[[ 3.  3.  3., 3.]
  [ 3.  3.  3., 3.]
  [ 3.  3.  3.. 3.]]

 [[ 8.  8.  8., 8.]
  [ 8.  8.  8., 8.]
  [ 8.  8.  8., 8.]]]
```

Comment: Interesting.. didn't know you can use np.newaxis with tensor variables instead of dimshuffle.

Comment: `dimshuffle` would of course work as well. But in general Theano is supposed to cover a maximal amount of numpy syntax. If your remark is specific to `np.newaxis`, observe that `(np.newaxis is None) == True`

Comment: You can also just use `None` instead of `np.newaxis`.

Comment: This is what my previous comment says. It is bad practice though.